# How is `exact` lookup different from `equal` lookup in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

How is `exact` lookup diffferent from `equal` lookup in Django

I have two queries

```
Blog.objects.get(title=title)

Blog.objects.get(title__exact=title)
```

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Django filter statement what's the difference between \_\_exact and equal sign (=)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963200/in-django-filter-statement-whats-the-difference-between-exact-and-equal-sign)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, the first one is the exactly same as second one.

Look at [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups):

```
Blog.objects.get(id__exact=14)  # Explicit form
Blog.objects.get(id=14)         # __exact is implied
```

Answer (score 2):

`exact` is the default.
Check the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups-intro):

> If you don’t provide a lookup type – that is, if your keyword argument doesn’t contain a double underscore – the lookup type is assumed to be `exact`.