# Django get/filter method default exact lookup not working

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to write a query to search model of myapp but. As stated in the official `Django documentation` and here at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963200/in-django-filter-statement-whats-the-difference-between-exact-and-equal-sign) the default behavior of __exact lookup if not working as it should.

For instance:

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>> from girvi.models import State
>>> State.objects.all()
[]
>>> s = State.objects.create(name='Uttar pradesh')
>>> State.objects.get(name='uttar pradesh')
<State: Uttar pradesh>
```

The above query should not work. It should return `[]` because I am looking for field with `name='uttar pradesh' against field`name='Uttar pradesh'`

```
>>> State.objects.get(name__exact='uttar pradesh')
<State: Uttar pradesh>
>>> State.objects.get(name__iexact='Uttar Pradesh')
<State: Uttar pradesh>
>>> State.objects.get(name__exact='Uttar Pradesh')
<State: Uttar pradesh>
```

Again the same behavior.

Please can someone explain it to me. What i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the database table's collation used? Even if you use __exact, and your table's collation is set to a case-insensitive variant, then __exact would still behave like __iexact.

Django's documentation states

> In MySQL, a database table’s “collation” setting determines whether exact comparisons are case-sensitive. This is a database setting, not a Django setting. It’s possible to configure your MySQL tables to use case-sensitive comparisons, but some trade-offs are involved. For more information about this, see the collation section in the databases documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer above is true, cause I've tried here and look what happened

```
>>> a = Postagem.objects.get(titulo = "Snippets Sublime text")
>>> a
<Postagem: 13 - Snippets Sublime text, 2014-09-17 00:37:08.268915+00:00>
>>> a = Postagem.objects.get(titulo = "snippets sublime text")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gpzim98/deploy/virtualenvs/BlogGP/local/lib/python2.7/site-ackages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/gpzim98/deploy/virtualenvs/BlogGP/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 307, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
    DoesNotExist: Postagem matching query does not exist.
```

Soon, it will depend of your collation. I'm use Postgre with collation pg_catalog."default", that is case-sensitive.

Comment: I just checked my MySQL server is using `latin1` as a default Charset and `latin1_swedish_c1` as a default collation.

Answer (score 0):

According to Django Docs, we need to update the collation for DB or table to get the expected output.

> By default, with a UTF-8 database, MySQL will use the utf8_general_ci collation. This results in all string equality comparisons being done in a case-insensitive manner. That is, "Fred" and "freD" are considered equal at the database level. If you have a unique constraint on a field, it would be illegal to try to insert both "aa" and "AA" into the same column, since they compare as equal (and, hence, non-unique) with the default collation. If you want case-sensitive comparisons on a particular column or table, change the column or table to use the utf8_bin collation.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#collation-settings