# In Django filter statement what's the difference between __in and equal sign (=)?

Tags: python, django

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963200/in-django-filter-statement-whats-the-difference-between-exact-and-equal-sign), I'd like to know if there any difference in writing

```
.filter(league_pk__in=[1,2,3])
```

and

```
.filter(league=[1,2,3])
```

I have tried both and they seem to return the same results in my code but nowhere in the documentation does it say that they're the same thing ([as with `__exact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)).

Can I safely assume the two forms are equal? Where is it documented?

Comment: league is manytomany field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing what the relation is defined on your models, we can't say for sure.  What I can give you is a way to check the query, that will tell you for sure if they are equivalent or not:

```
print your_qs.filter(league_pk__in=[1,2,3]).query
print your_qs.filter(league=[1,2,3]).query
```

And look at the sql generated to see what's actually going on at the db level.

Comment: I've used this method and saw that the generated queries are identical, despite `league` being a ForeignKey. Perhaps there are some cases where it is different and some where it is the same? Your answer solves any possible further question, though. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to find a ticket where this "feature" was added.  Could I ask what version of django you are on?  Earlier versions can try to convert list [1,2,3] to integer and, of course, fail here.

Comment: I was wrong. It doesn't work if you provide a list (as I did in my question): you have to use "__in" if you provide a Python list. However, it DOES work if you provide a Django QuerySet. In this case, you can use both "__in" and "=" and they have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think roughly for your first query, it's doing:

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE model.league_id IN (SELECT id FROM league WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3))
```

For the second query, it's doing:

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE model.league_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```